Suppose P,Q are two points on the same side of the line AB. R is a point on the segment PQ such that PR = λPQ.
Suppose P,Q are two points on the same side of the line AB. R is a point on the segment PQ such that PR = λPQ. Prove that [ABR] = (1 - λ)[ABP] + λ[ABQ] where [.] this denotes area of that polygon.
I tried to apply area lemma but I am not sure how to apply it.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You can use coordinate geometry, and use the internal section formula :)

i have to do it by plane geometry

What area lemma are you referring to?  Also, please show all the analytical  work that you have done to attack the problem.  Please do not respond in the comments.  Instead, respond by editing your posted question.   Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

Using simple trigonometry

$$h_{APB}=PT\sin \theta$$
$$h_{AQB}=QT\sin \theta$$
$$h_{ARB}=(PT+PR)\sin \theta =\{PT+(QT-PT)\lambda\} \sin \theta$$
Then
$$(1-\lambda)[APB]+(\lambda)[APQ]=\frac{AB\sin\theta}{2}\bigg(PT(1-\lambda)+QT\lambda\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{AB\sin\theta}{2}\bigg(PT+(QT-PT)\lambda\bigg)=[ARB]$$
